# website preloading

Tags: jquery, image, preloader

This is my website: http://justxp.plutohost.net/jonydesigns/index.php

As you see the menu images jumping when you hover on them because the hover images hasn't changed or loader yet.

and the images in overall.

I want to make a preloader that shows a loading.gif icon while loading the page, once loaded, just show the page or fade out to the page.

Are there any preloaders tutorials for that? I have googled website preloaders, all i found was some custom css preloading bars, and preloaders for specify images.

I need a preloader for the whole website.

Does any one know where I can find one? Thanks!

Comment: You may try jquery load : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: You should be using sprites. Wait, on second look, are you using images of text? I'm not sure how to explain how wrong that is – text is the one thing that the internet is awesome for! Images of text are pretty much always the wrong thing to do, unless it's super fancy (your main animated bit falls into the 'fair enough' use case!)

Comment: In fact, the CSS relating to that whole nav is pretty weird - you have a transition set loads of times, instead of just once on `#menu div`. Also, ms-transition isn't needed. That should make the CSS quite a bit more concise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preload the images, just put this in your initialization (you don't have to wait for document.ready to run this):

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/hex-codes/003366.png";
var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/hex-codes/FF9900.png"
```

or ( jQuery : )

```
$.preloadImages = function()
{
  for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++)
  {
    jQuery("<img />", {style:'display:none'}).attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Usage :

```
$.preloadImages("img2_thumb.jpg", "img1_thumb.jpg",    "img3_thumb.jpg");
```

*ofcourse- the images should be the hover images.*

Answer (score 0):

For the Top banners, you need to preload the images:
http://rah1x.tumblr.com/post/32390880686/pre-load-images

For the rest of the site, where you want loading image while the image loads, here is something that will get you started.This works for individual image, however, you can simple make it as an event for image load using jquery:
http://rah1x.tumblr.com/post/32450670309/show-loading-while-image-src-changes